# angularjs custom REST action and error handling

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, rest, error-handling, flask

I'm having some trouble with error handling in a little angularjs application. I'm interacting with a Flask backend and a Postgres DB.

I have a factory service

```
appointServices.factory('Appointments', ['$resource', function($resource){
return $resource(someUrl, {}, {
    query: { ... }
    ,
    create: {
    method: 'POST'
    ,url: 'http://somedomain:port/new/:name/:start/:end/:treatment'
    ,params: { start: '@start', end: '@end', name: '@name', treatment: '@treatment' }
    ,isArray:false
    }
});
}
```

]);

Inside a controller I'm making the following call

```
Appointments.create($scope.appointment, function(value, responseHeaders) {
   // success handler
   console.debug('success: ', JSON.stringify(value));
}, function(httpResponse) {
   // error handler
   console.debug('error: ', JSON.stringify(httpResponse));
});
```

Here `$scope.appointment` contains the relevant parameters for the `create` action.

Now, in the backend I'm able to catch DB errors involving constraints and I'm trying to return an error code with a 'meaningful' message. So I have a python method

```
def create(name, start, end, treatment):
  try:
    ...
    transaction_status = 'ok'
    code = 200

  except IntegrityError as e:
    ...
    transaction_status = 'IntegrityError'
    code = 500
  finally:
    ...

  return make_response(transaction_status, code)
```

Everything works fine, I'm able to talk to the backend, create new data and insert this in the DB. As I said, any violation of the constraints is detected and the backend responds

```
curl -X POST "http://somedomain:port/new/foo/bar/baz/qux" -v
...
< HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
...
IntegrityError
```

So, the problem is, no matter whether the action `create` was successful or not, the intended error handler specified inside the controller is always fired. Moreover, I always end up with a status code `404` in the `httpResponse`. Firebug shows correctly the code `500` as above, though.

Anybody has any idea of why I'm getting this behavior?
Any suggestions on how to improve the error handling mechanism are also welcome.
Thx in advance.

P.S. Following the documentation on [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) I have also tried variations on the factory service call, e.g.

```
Appointments.create({}, $scope.appointment, successCallback, errorCallback);
Appointments.create($scope.appointment, {}, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

with the same results.

**Update:**

Forgot to mention the important fact that I'm interacting with the backend via CORS requests. The `POST` request in `create` above is having place with the `OPTIONS` method instead. As I mentioned everything is working correctly except for the error response.

Under further investigation, I tried to isolate the factory service, in case I did something wrong, and I also tried the approach shown in the credit card example (`$resource` docs), but with no positive result.

However, I came up with two workarounds. Firstly, I was able to create a plain *JQuery* `POST` request, as in the [example](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) shown in the docs. This time, the request is **not** replaced by `OPTIONS` and I got the error code correctly.

I also managed to connect to the backend with the low-level `$http` service as follows:

```
var urlBase = 'http://somedomain:port/new/:name/:start/:end/:treatment';

var url = urlBase.replace(/:name/g, $scope.appointment.name);
url = url.replace(/:start/g, $scope.appointment.start);
url = url.replace(/:end/g, $scope.appointment.end);
url = url.replace(/:treatment/g, $scope.appointment.treatment);

// force method to be POST
var futureResponse = $http({ method: 'POST', url: url });
futureResponse.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.debug('success: ', JSON.stringify(data));
});
futureResponse.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.group('Error');
    console.debug(JSON.stringify(status));
    console.debug(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.groupEnd();
});
```

This time, as in the case of JQuery, the request is done effectively with `POST` and error codes are correctly received.

Notice also that I'm **not** calling `$http.post` but I set the method to `POST` as part of the object parameter to `$http`, otherwise the connection takes places with `OPTIONS` *as before*.

Still trying to figure out what is happening with `$resource`.